# mysql or avg or should i use php?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to find an average of an average with a mysql query.

I have 12 criteria  and i can get an average for a column but i can not find the average of average,

Am trying to to work out a total rating of 12 criteria.

I think there are a few ways to go about this.

1. is to divide the total score by the number votes, problem is each row has a possibility of 12 votes.
2. get the avg totals, find our # of values set then divide the avg totals by # of values set

I need the number that i am dividing the total by to change depending on votes.
1 used can input 12 votes in 1 row
2 users could input a total of 18 votes in 2 rows, which means 1 user has not completed 6 votes[image: table data]
The table has been shortened for testing purposes to columns that contain votes. I have posted this already, sorry for repost, but am starting to understand what help i roughly need

Comment: Please, show your tables' structure, otherwise it's impossible to help.

Comment: **"This sounds so simple"**. Maybe it does to you, but for the rest of us outside of the loop, we don't really know enough information about your values and what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: sorry am just pretty desperate for this to work, been nearly a week on this, and i feel like am in a loop.

Comment: Okay, so you're looking for how to count the number of votes cast? Sorry, the question is a bit ambiguous. Can you do the math (fully written out) for your example?

Comment: example: for shop_id 1 
35/ 5 = 5

What am not trying to do is:
avg(comfort) as a1, avg(service) as a2, avg(service) as a3 .....
then add up the average and divide by 12, that gives me an average of average.

Yes, am trying to get count number of votes cast, the 0 was a problem so i have set the 0's to NULL now as 0 was effecting the average. sorry for the confusion, brain is racing abit

Answer (score 0):

First, in order to decide whether a user has voted or not, you need to have something other than an integer stored in the field until a vote is added. I would suggest `NULL`.

Next, add another column to the table for the user's average rating. This would be calculated using the columns in the row that **don't** have a `null` value. Example semi-pseudo code:

```
// Get users row from database
// Use a query like: 
// SELECT comfort,service,friendliness,food,drinks,toilet,music FROM myTable WHERE user_id = 123;
$row = $db->fetchrow($userid);

// Loop through and find out how many are valid
// Also add values together
foreach($row as $col)
{
   if( !is_null($col) )
   {
      $numValidColumns++;
      $totalVote = $totalVote + $col; 
   }
}

// Calculate user's average
$userAvg = $totalVote/$numValidColumns;

// Add to db for this row in new field you just made
$db->insert(...);
```

Something like this would allow you to calculate the user's average save it. If they add another vote, you would recalculate this average.

The final step is to query **all** the rows and add the values of the *user average* column together. Divide it by the total number of rows to arrive at an overall average.

Hope that is on the right track for you.

Comment: just reading now, just trying to get this to work, it appears as if this is the path.
I forgot to mention i have more than 1 table. One table is 'shops' other is 'ratings'.   I have added a 'rating_total' column to the 'shop' table as each shop has 1 shop total, or should i be adding a total rating to each row of 'ratings' ( that is 1 total which is updated as the users adds more values) or is that exactly what you meant? Sorry about my lack of understanding,

Comment: I was saying add a column to your ratings table holding the average of each set of ratings. Then you can create an average of all of those either on the fly, or store it in your shops table.

Comment: am a little confused about the process still, am trying to do this, not going so well, cant word this struggle in this small space

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar using a temporary table. First do the average for each column and then the general average or whatever operation you do which returns the values you need. Don't forget to drop the temp table though.